# Observation of order of array elements

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, nsmutablearray, key-value-observing

There's any chance to observe for order elements of array via KVO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NSKeyValueObserving protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) includes KVO notification methods for ordered to-many relationships (i.e. an NSMutableArray property of an object):

```
- willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:
- didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:
```

So you can see when an array's elements change and then make sure they're in the right order. You might also take a look at [key-value validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173), which could give you a way to make sure an array stays sorted.